# Azure App Service - Slot swapping files get locked

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

The erorr occurs when there is an acctive traffic to the service
1. Deploy o staging
2. Swap slot with prod
3. application return 502

logs shows

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions, Version=1.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

The error message is not consistent, it could be Swagger DLL was locked or System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.

the big question is. Are slots sharing same files ? how does exactly works ? I ssume that each slot is a separate App .

Comment: Literally, it should swap the endpoints between the old and the currently deployed app. Concept of slot is a junk in modern app development. Apart from that Azure serves with more pain in using them.

Comment: I have a short term solution. added an extra app restart, for some reason "Azure App  Service deploy" with options "Deploy to Slot" and "take app offline " does not really work well. Our next big step si to use service fabric so I guess the problem will go away .

Comment: For me, 5 minutes pass between uploading files (via zip deploy) and swapping slots (and this error).  Yeah, what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Might be of interest to others, but I added a line to restart the web app (production slot), after swapping.

```
az webapp restart -g ResourceGroupName -n AppServiceName
```

Comment: service fabric sorted it 5 years ago.